# What should be taught in Number Theory for secondary pupil?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request

I have a brother who is in 8th of secondary school. He likes mathematics but he didn't study it systematically though he is quite smart. I decide to teach him from basics number theory on. I did taught him about prime number, decomposition of natural number to prime number, divisor, greatest common divisor, common multiple, least common multiple, and basic idea about congruence.

He can understand and apply the theory quite well, but our problems are

1. We need more exercises for him to practice
2. I want to teach him Diophantine equation.

So besides the above parts, what should I teach him more about Number theory?

Which textbook should I use?

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Pell's equations and continued fractions

Comment: Get any book on elementary number theory and start going through it with him.  When/ if you encounter something that requires high school prereqs (the quadratic formula, synthetic division, etc), take some time to go through that before coming back to the number theory book.

Comment: Or, for a book specifically for students in 7th - 10th graders, [Art of Problem Solving](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/store/list/aops-curriculum) has a book on number theory.  I haven't looked through it, but I've seen some of their other books and their stuff seems pretty good.

Comment: One of the most important problem is exercise to practice and I don't know any book :(. I'm now teach him congruence with the book of Burton.

Comment: What is 8th of secondary school? Different countries have different terms.Find some books on Introduction to Number Theory. The preface or intro to the book should tell you what background,if any,is required of the reader.You should also find a book with a chapter on the logical (axiomatic) foundations of the real number system $R$ as you cannot avoid irrationals for long. Many people graduate high school with vague or confused ideas about $R$

Comment: As an after-thought, try this one :If $x\in R$ and if for each $r\in R^+$  there are infinitely many $(a,b)\in Z\times Z^+$ such that $0<|x-a/b|<r/b$ then $x$ is irrational.